Analyzing the sensititivity of the estimate of a parameter to noise with Monte Carlo simulation
I am working with a perspective camera. I have the following equation for projection:
$$
v = \frac{f*y}{z-z_c}
$$
Here v is the coordinate in the image plane: $v \in [-1,1]$,
f is the focal length, y is the distance perpendicular to the optical axis, z is the distance along an axis trough the optical axis and $z_c$ is the position of the camera along this axis.
Assuming that I know that f=2, $y∈[-0.5,0.5]$, $z_c = -1$ and z = 0 I want to analyze this equation with respect to sensitivity to noise.
I do this by choosing N linearly spaced points $y_i$
on the interval [-0.5,0.5] and calculate the corresponding v values. Next I add normal distributed noise to the y, z  and v values:
$$
yn=y + N(0,σ_y)
$$
$$
zn = N(0,σ_z)
$$
$$
vn=v + N(0,σ_v)
$$
Next I estimate f:
$$
vn = \hat{f}\frac{yn}{(1 + zn)}
$$
using least squares (numpy.polyfit(yn/(1+zn), vn, 1))
).
As a measure of how good an estimate f is I introduce the projection error:
$$
\epsilon(y) = \hat{v} − v = (\hat{f} - f)y 
$$
Define:
$$
\beta := \hat{f} - f
$$
I am looking for a bound:
$$
|\beta|<= \beta_{max}(σ_y,σ_z,σ_v,N)
$$
with 95 % confidence.
I imagine that finding this analytically will be very hard?
Therefore I attempt to use Monte Carlo.
I find that for
$$
\sigma_y = \sigma_z = \sigma_v = 2.5e-4
$$
$$
N = 100
$$
$$
\beta_{max} = 4.0 e-4
$$

Here is the code I used:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = 2

s_y = 2.5e-4
s_z = 2.5e-4
s_v = 2.5e-4

N = 100

y = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, N)
v = f*y

iterations = 10*1000
f_estimate = np.zeros(iterations)
for i in range(0, iterations):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    yn = y + rng.normal(0, s_y, N)
    zn = rng.normal(0, s_z, N)
    vn = v + rng.normal(0, s_v, N)
    f_estimate[i] = np.polyfit(yn/(1+zn), vn, 1)[0]
    #print(f_estimate[i])

df = f_estimate - f
abs_df = np.abs(df)

b_max = np.percentile(abs_df, 95)
print(b_max)

plt.hist(abs_df, 100)
plt.xlabel('beta_max')
plt.axvline(b_max, color='g')
plt.title('Histogram for b_max. s_y = s_z = s_v = 2.5e-4, N = 100')
plt.show()

Am I doing this correctly?
